# Trouble traversing XML Object in foreach($object as $key => $value);

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object, foreach

```
print_r($value->billTo);
```

```
OUTPUT
 SimpleXMLElement Object (  
     [firstName] => Joseph  
     [lastName] => Stalin  
     [address] => 12345 Test Lane  
     [city] => Navarre  
     [state] => FL  
     [zip] => 32561  
     [country] => USA  
     [phoneNumber] => 4025555555 )
```

```
foreach($value->billTo as $classx => $valuex){
  $DOM_payments .= "\t\t  <p class='".$classx."'>".$valuex."</p>\n";
}

echo $DOM_payments;
```

```
OUTPUT
<p class='billTo'></p>
```

It should be printing:

```
<p class='firstname'>Joseph</p>  
...  
...  
<p class='phoneNumber'>4025555555</p>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to make it so I am not getting my expected results.  Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have got to convert the `SimpleXMLElement` to an array to use it in a `foreach`

[see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#99729)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I changed the foreach loop to use (array)$value->billTo instead of just $value->billTo