# PHP - Echo key value of the array items

Tags: php

I need to echo the key value of an array.

This is how im outputting my array:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
  $item->title
}
```

I've tried adding:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $key => $item)
```

But the value I echo just comes out as: `item`

Any ideas?

Var Dump of item results:

```
var_dump($xml->channel->item);

    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (5) { 
["title"]=>  string(33) "BA and union agree to end dispute" 
["description"]=>  string(118) "British Airways and the Unite union reach an agreement which could end the long-running dispute between the two sides." 
["link"]=>  string(61) "http://www.bbc.co.uk/go/rss/int/news/-/news/business-13373638" 
["guid"]=>  string(43) "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-13373638" 
["pubDate"]=>  string(29) "Thu, 12 May 2011 12:33:38 GMT" 
}
```

Comment: have you put `echo` in front of `$item->title`? try `var_dump($xml->channel->item` and debug whether it is already an `array` or not.

Comment: I think it's a SimpleXML Object and won't necessarily dump out as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
$data = $xml->channel->item;

if (is_object($data) === true)
{
    $data = get_object_vars($data);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_keys($data));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This gives me the key for each entry under item:

Comment: @CLiown: And you don't want that? `foreach (array_keys($data) as $key) { echo $key; }`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>foreach($xml->channel->item as $key => $item)
        echo $key;
    }</s>

ADDED:

Check the answer here for converting it to array [Trouble traversing XML Object in foreach($object as $key => $value);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396977/trouble-traversing-xml-object-in-foreachobject-as-key-value)

Comment: @CLiown that's because it's not a real array. It's an SimpleXMLElement, which mimics being an array without real indexes, just lots of values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an array but a SimpleXMLElement. So loop through the children nodes and output the name.

```
foreach ( $xml->channel->item->children() as $child ) {
  echo $child->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you could try to convert `XML` the into `Array`

```
function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{
        foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
            $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

        return $out;
}
```

and then access it with foreach.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$x = new SimpleXMLElement(<<<EOXML
<root>
   <node>Some Text</node>
</root>
EOXML
);

xml2array($x,&$out);
var_dump($out);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(1) {
  ["node"]=>
  string(9) "Some Text"
}
```

Comment: It is just simple recursive method with parsers all nodes of XML. Try `xml2array($xml, $out)` and then `foreach($out as $key=>$value){}`

Comment: Result is NULL when I var_dump($out)

Comment: Ouups, mistake. `$out` by reference, `xml2array($xml, &$out)`